# How can I instantiate a core data object for SwiftUI preview?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I have the following Core Data object defined in my project.

[image: Project class defined in Core Data]

Now, I would like to instantiate one so I can send it in to my ProjectDetail class when generating a SwiftUI preview.

Here's how the `ProjectDetail` View is defined:

```
struct ProjectDetail: View {
    var project: Project
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack{
                Text(project.id?.uuidString ?? "no id!")
                Text(project.title ?? "no title!")
                    .font(.title2)
            }
        }
```

Now I just want to pass in a basic Project object to that view during the preview generation but this literally crashes.

```
struct ProjectDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   
    static var previews: some View {
        
       ProjectDetail( project: Project())
       // Text("No preview")
    }
}
```

What do I need to do so I can instantiate a `Project` object and set it's properties so I can see my preview?

Comment: If mine is a duplicate of that other question, then the other question should definitely have it's question edited, because the question that is posed is 100% different than mine.

Comment: Why not simply giving a sample data to the preview like `ProjectDetail(project: Project(altered: "01/01/23", completed: true, created: "01/01/23", id: "1234", pdescription: "Hello", title: "Hello"))`?